# What is a word for future uncertainty that may cause serious consequences?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe a future uncertainty that may cause serious consequences? For example,

> There is a lot of uncertainties in the progress of this project.

But I would like to replace "uncertainties" here with another word that also connotes the seriousness of possible consequences if back luck hits in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*risk* works:

> the possibility that something bad or unpleasant (such as an injury or a loss) will happen

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/risk#other-entry-1))

It's a widely used term within [project management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_risk_management).

---

I'd modify your sample sentence further: the word 'is' needs to be plural, and "in the progress" sounds off to me. Better would be something like:

> There are a lot of risks endangering the progress of this project.

Answer (score 2):

Glorfindel's answer of "risk" is an excellent one, especially in context of business.

If "risk" isn't exactly what you're after, "pitfall" may also suffice:

> A hidden or not easily recognized danger or difficulty

Source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pitfall)

Your example sentence could read:

> There are a lot of potential pitfalls in the progress of this project.